# Static worker unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGTERM

Tags: next.js, vercel, sigterm

When I run pNpm build locally, it builds successfully without any errors. However, when I deploy it on Vercel, it keeps failing and returns this error:

```
Static worker unexpectedly exited with code: null and signal: SIGTERM
```

I'm pretty sure I don't have `.next` folder in my repository.

This is my `next.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.node$/,
      use: "node-loader",
    });

    return config;
  },
  images: {
    domains: ["https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/"],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

[image]

Comment: Have you actually taken a look at the [linked documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/static-page-generation-timeout) section? Next.js tries to restart the worker pool of the static page generation when no progress happens for a while, to avoid hanging builds.

Comment: I increased the `staticPageGenerationTimeout` to 180 and it's working now, thank you @FabioNettis

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to delete .next folder and rebuild

rm -rf .next